# Add property to properties file if null

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to add a new property to config.properties if it isn't there. Is there any way to do this?

My current config class looks like this:

```
package com.template;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config {

    static File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/Electrocode Productions/template");

    public static void add() {
        if(!folder.exists()) {
            try {
                folder.mkdirs();
            } catch(SecurityException e) {
                Log.error(e);
            }
        }

        Properties config = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;
        Path filePath = Paths.get(folder + "/config.properties");    
        if(!(filePath == null)) {
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/config.properties");

                config.setProperty("log", "true");

                config.store(output, null);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.error(e);
            } finally {
                if(output !=null) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.error(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String get(String value) {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(folder + "/config.properties");

            config.load(input);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.error(e);
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return config.getProperty(value).trim();
    }
}
```

This is working, as it won't overwrite the file if you edit it, but if you delete an entry, you need to completely delete the whole file to re-add that entry.

My ultimate goal is for you to be able to close the program, edit the config file, then reopen the config file with the new arguments, but if you delete an argument, it won't crash to program because it relies on an answer from the config file. (I hope that makes sense. It's basically like most video games).

Comment: This isn't super-clear.  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate?

Comment: @Oliver found that the problem was just I couldn't "return null;" I had to change it to "return "unknow";" then use get(value).equals("unknow") instead of .equals(null). Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate the value you get from the Properties before using it. e.g. you can't `.trim()` a value which wasn't here.

```
public class Config {

    static final File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/Electrocode Productions/template");
    static final File file = new File(folder, "config.properties");

    public static void add() throws IOException {
        if (file.exists())
            return;

        // create directories as needed.
        folder.mkdirs();

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.setProperty("log", "true");

        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            config.store(out, null);
        }
    }

    public static String get(String key, String defaultValue) {
        if (!file.exists())
            return defaultValue;

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            Properties config = new Properties();

            config.load(input);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.error(e);
            return defaultValue;
        }

        String value = config.getProperty(key);
        if (value == null)
            return defaultValue;
        value = value.trim();
        if (value.isEmpty())
            return defaultValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code! I found that the problem was just I couldn't "return null;" I had to change it to "return "unknow";" then use get(value).equals("unknow") instead of .equals(null). Once again that you for your help.

Comment: @BudSkywalker this is where using a default value is best. You can pass in the value you want it to be if it's unknown. Btw you can use null but the comparison must be `if (value == null)`